# Use apply on two data.frame's

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

If I had a `data.frame` X and wanted to apply a function `foo` to each of its rows, I would just run `apply(X, 1, foo)`. This is all well-known and simple.

Now imagine I have another `data.frame` Y and the following function:

```r
mean_of_sum <- function(x,y) {
  return(mean(x+y))
}
```

Is there a way to write an "apply equivalent" to the following loop:

```r
my_loop_fun <- function(X, Y)
  results <- numeric(nrow(X))
  for(i in 1: length(results)) {
    results[i] <- mean_of_sum(X[i,], Y[i,])
  }
  return(results)
```

If such an "apply syntax" exists, would it be more efficient than my "good" old loop?

Comment: What does `mean_of_sum` supposed to do ? Assuming there are two columns in both the dataframe `X` and `Y` and first row of `X` is `2 `and `3` and `Y` is `4` and `5`. What should it return?

Comment: It should add ```x```and ```y``` component-wise, then calculate the mean of the resulting vector. For your example, it should return the average of (2+4) and (3+5), so: 7. Of course my real function is more complicated, I am just trying to show a minimal example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(X)), function(i) mean_of_sum(X[i,], Y[i,]))
```

You apply the function on the sequence `1, 2, ..., n` (where `n` is the number of rows ) and in each "iteration" you evaluate `mean_of_sum` for the i-th row.

Comment: Simply brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

We can `split` every row of `X` and `Y` in list and use `mapply` to apply the function. Changing the function `mean_of_sum` a bit to convert one-row dataframe to numeric

```
mean_of_sum <- function(x,y) {
   return(mean(as.numeric(x) + as.numeric(y)))
}
```

Consider an example,

```
X <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
Y <- data.frame(c = 11:15, d = 16:20)

mapply(mean_of_sum, split(X, seq_len(nrow(X))), split(Y, seq_len(nrow(Y))))

# 1  2  3  4  5 
#17 19 21 23 25
```

where `X` and `Y` are

```
X
#  a  b
#1 1  6
#2 2  7
#3 3  8
#4 4  9
#5 5 10
Y
#   c  d
#1 11 16
#2 12 17
#3 13 18
#4 14 19
#5 15 20
```

So the first value 17 is counted as

```
mean(c(1 + 11, 6 + 16))
#[1] 17
```

and so on for next values.

Comment: This is OK, but forces me to redefine ```mean_sum```, which is a bit of an inconvenience in my case